# SQL incorrect syntax near a table name after FROM and before INNER JOIN.

Tags: sql, exception

Hi I have this SELECT query. I've tried excuting the query on the SQL Pane on Visual Studio 2008 and it works. However when I run the page (this is an asp.net page), it throws an SQL Exception saying I have an incorrect syntax near Schedules.

```
string selectSchedString = "SELECT Subjects.subject_title, Schedules.class_day, CAST(MIN(Schedules.time_in) AS varchar(10)) + ' - ' + CAST(MAX(Schedules.time_out) AS varchar(10)) AS Expr1" +
            "FROM Schedules "+ //The exception points here       
            "INNER JOIN Subjects ON Schedules.subject_id = Subjects.subject_id " +
            "INNER JOIN Student ON Student.section_id = " + currentSection + " " +
            "GROUP BY Subjects.subject_title, Schedules.class_day";
```

Any ideas? As I've said, I tried excuting this on the SQL pane and it worked. Is there any special condition in asp.net that I've missed or something?

Answer (score 7):

You are missing any white space between the end of the first line and `FROM`

Change `AS Expr1"` to `AS Expr1 "`

Comment: Oh gosh. I spent the last hour retyping the word Schedules, putting spaces, assigning it to different variables. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ha ha, sometimes a second pair of eyes can spot this stuff easier.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the concatinated string is not correct try:

```
string selectSchedString = "SELECT Subjects.subject_title, Schedules.class_day, CAST(MIN(Schedules.time_in) AS varchar(10)) + ' - ' + CAST(MAX(Schedules.time_out) AS varchar(10)) AS Expr1" +
            " FROM Schedules "+ //The exception points here       
            " INNER JOIN Subjects ON Schedules.subject_id = Subjects.subject_id " +
            " INNER JOIN Student ON Student.section_id = " + currentSection + " " +
            " GROUP BY Subjects.subject_title, Schedules.class_day";
```

Notice the empty spaces.